Serilog lower loglevel of exceptions with custom type
I am using a nuget package that throws (a lot of) validation exceptions of a certain custom type (eg CustomValidationException). I want to throw these exceptions at my client so I can't just catch them and handle them. But at the moment they greatly pollute my database with errors that aren't really errors to me.
Is it possible to filter these exceptions in Serilog, and lower their loglevel to Information? I do want to see that they are happening, I just don't want them to be errors.
I've tried implementing an Enricher, but that doesn't allow me to change the loglevel. I've looked at filters, but they seem to completely remove the errors from my logging, that's too rigorous.
